# Does photon energy affect deflection of a beam of light in a gravitational field?

Tags: general-relativity, particle-physics, speed-of-light, mass-energy

Does photon energy affect deflection of a beam of light in a gravitational field?

According to general theory of relativity angular deflection of a beam of light in a gravitational field is
$$φ = \frac{4GM}{Rc^2}$$

means whatever the energy of a photon is `φ` is the same.
And the consequence of this fact means that whatever a "picture" is "sent" we will receive it with the same "color scheme" (corrected for Hubble's law).

Is it correct?

Comment: No to title. [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens#Explanation_in_terms_of_spacetime_curvature). Yes to punchline question.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421) to type equations and mathematical symbols.

Comment: BTW, that deflection equation is an approximation. It's ok when $R$ is large compared to the Schwarzschild radius, but not when you get close to the BH. I have some graphs here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49874/16685